# Is there an onBackPressed() alternative for a service?

Tags: android, service, back

I know that services cannot implement Back key press and I understand the rationale. But there is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mohammad.adib.sidebar.lite) called SideBar (on Play Store) that reacts to back key presses. It is a service that adds a view as system overlay and removes the view when the back key is pressed. Can anybody explain how this is done?

Here is another [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lazyswipe&hl=en) that does it well. I have scoured the web, but have not found a solution to this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I'm facing a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51438677/949280).

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            removeView();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably done using [system alert windows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) - so the service creates and manages a window that is added to the window manager, which has a custom [callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html) set on it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do you intercept the key event in the service and pass it to the window or the windowManager?

Comment: you got any example?

Answer (score -2):

[***here***](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/)
is nice example to addview in Service and also you can use listeners if you want in services.

i was also looking for the listeners implementation in service and finally found it.

remember to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

and add your service class

```
<application>
.
 .
  <service android:name=".YourServiceClass"></service>
 .
.
</application>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml.