# Android: Is it possible to detect physical Back key pressed from a Service

Tags: android, service, key, back, listen

I want to listen & get notified - Not overriding - to the physical Back key when pressed from a Service.

Most threads says it's not possible unless I have an activity in Foreground.

I found this thread: [Is there an onBackPressed() alternative for a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140052/is-there-an-onbackpressed-alternative-for-a-service)

And there is an answer says:

> It is probably done using system alert windows - so the service creates and manages a window that is added to the window manager, which has a custom callback set on it.

But there is no details or reference to a link. Is it possible with this suggestion? Any available example.

**Targeting Android v4.1.2 & forward**