# Android - How to catch back navigation key pressed from background service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'll need to check from background service any event on device to calculate time from last user action. (Android 4.4)  I've implement handle any touch on device (use background view with `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` (from [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)), implement volume key handle (use `BroadcastReceiver (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)`), implement home key watcher, usb charger event.

But I cannot find how to handle back key press from background.

Is anybody knows how to catch 'back navigation' key from service?

Is it possible?

It might exist an easiest way to handle all events from service (touch, keys, buttons...)

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140052/is-there-an-onbackpressed-alternative-for-a-service

Comment: Yes,  but no event received.